# jQuery - Random positioned divs inside parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

My problem is the following:

I have three divs with different classes, they are in a bigger container div.
Is there any way to give them a random position inside the parent div after refreshing the page?
With the code below i can almost achieve this, but sometimes some of the divs just fall out of the main div.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
$(".img-1, .img-2, .img-3").each(function(index) {
  $(this).css({
    left: Math.random() * ($(".main").width() - $(this).width()),
    top: Math.random() * ($(".main").height() - $(this).height())
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.img-1 {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.img-2 {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: green;
}

.img-3 {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="img-1"></div>
  <div class="img-2"></div>
  <div class="img-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `position: absolute;` for the `.img-X` DIVs, so that their positions will be absolute relative to the closest positioned ancestor. Then you have to use `position: relative;` for the `.main` so that it will meet that criteria.

```js
$(".img-1, .img-2, .img-3").each(function(index) {
  $(this).css({
    left: Math.random() * ($(".main").width() - $(this).width()),
    top: Math.random() * ($(".main").height() - $(this).height())
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.img-1 {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.img-2 {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.img-3 {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="img-1">1</div>
  <div class="img-2">2</div>
  <div class="img-3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, i missed that! Thanks very much @Barmar!